# Layering Views on a SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to build a simple game. I have a SurfaceView, on which I draw the background for the game:

```
Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
//draw on canvas....
surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

I have a View that I want to 'layer' on top of the SurfaceView, but I still want to be able to see the background underneath it. How do I draw the view on top of the SurfaceView. The View has its own onDraw method, with an associated canvas, so I'm assuming that I need to place the View on top of the SurfaceView where I drew the background?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you've tried.

Comment: Don't use `SurfaceView` as a parent view. Add it to a FrameLayout(since it allows vertical stacking). You should be able to add the custom View as an overlay.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more efficient way to to do this, but when it comes to stacking views on top of one another, you could put the SurfaceView inside a FrameLayout, and then put the view you want on top after the SurfaceView in the XML, but still inside the FrameLayout (meaning it's drawn later, and thus on top). This will accomplish the stacking you desire.

If you wish to position the view that will go on top of the SurfaceView anywhere else than exactly matching it, or the top left, then you could use a RelativeLayout where you layout the SurfaceView with alightParentLeft, alightParentTop, alignParentBottom, and alightParentRight all set to true. Then again having the view you want drawn on top coming after the SurfaceView in xml will draw it on top, and you can position it wherever you want.

Now as for you wanting to the view on top of the SurfaceView to be see through, you can do that by setting it's alpha value. if you are aiming for 3.0+ you can just use a view's .setAlpha method, but if you are aiming for lower, you could set a zero millisecond AlphaAnimation to set the alpha of the view (There may be a better way to do this, but this is the only way I to set alpha on views pre honeycomb).

Hope this helps! Best of luck!